# jQuery - Add new div on click after last matching div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add new div on click @ the end of last match.

```
    <form id="form">
        <div class="border item-block">
            <p><b>Color :</b> silver </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="available_colors[silver][color_name]" value="silver">
            <input type="text"  name="available_colors[silver][color_image]" value="SM-9436RE_B_BEAUTY.JPG">
        </div>
        <a style = "float : left; margin-top: 50px" class="button add">Add</a>
    </form>
```

On click I want to create div with input as this attr available_colors[NEW][0][color_name] and so on.

Like this

```
    <form id="form">
                <div class="border item-block">
                    <p><b>Color :</b> silver </p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="available_colors[silver][color_name]" value="silver">
                    <input type="text"  name="available_colors[silver][color_image]" value="SM-9436RE_B_BEAUTY.JPG">
                </div>
                <div class="border item-block">
                    <p><b>Color :</b> <input type="text" name="available_colors[NEW][0][color_name]" value=""></p>
                    <input type="text"  name="available_colors[NEW][0][color_image]" value="">
                </div>
                <a style = "float : left; margin-top: 50px" class="button add">Add</a
     </form>
```

On second click want to add this div

```
<div class="border item-block">
        <p><b>Color :</b> <input type="text" name="available_colors[NEW][1][color_name]" value=""></p>
        <input type="text"  name="available_colors[NEW][1][color_image]" value="">
 </div>
```

I try this approach but i am not getting filed. I tried to clone the last div but i dont know how I can switch all input name attributes.

```
$('a.add').click(function(){
        var form, fields;
        //$('.item-block').last().clone().insertAfter($('.item-block').last());
        form = $("#form");
        fields = form.find("input[name^='available_colors[NEW]']");
        alert(fields[0]);
    });
```

Can some one advice me know this?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: On a slightly unrelated note, why are you first defining your variables without any value and then assigning the value in the next line? That seems pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the jquery `.after()` method:
[after() - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/after/).
So you could use it like so:

```
$('a.add').click(function(){
    // get a handle on the last instance of the div
    var lastDiv = $('#form').find('div.item-block').last();

    // create the new div you want to add
    var newDiv = lastDiv.clone();
    newDiv.find('input').attr('name','available_colors[NEW][1][color_image]');

    // add the new div after the last instance of the item-block div
    lastDiv.after(newDiv);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the **A element on your example is broken**.

You can use a **global var**:

```
var count = 0;
```

... and a **structuring** function:

```
function addNewBlock(){
    count++;
    return '<div class="border item-block">'+
        '<p><b>Color :</b> <input type="text" name="available_colors[NEW]['+(count-1)+'][color_name]" value=""></p>'+
        '<input type="text"  name="available_colors[NEW]['+(count-1)+'][color_image]" value="">'+
        '</div>';
}
```

... and the **adding** function:

```
$('a.add').click(function(){
    // here, you get the new structured HTML object
    $html = addNewBlock();

    //and you just need to append it:
    $("#form").append($html);
});
```

It doesn't work if the `A element` is inside the `FORM tag`.
You need to *cut-paste* `<a style = "float : left; margin-top: 50px" class="button add">Add</a>` for below all the FORM code.

jQuery Append documentation: http://api.jquery.com/append/
I guess it'll work for you.